# Silverlight ImageTools.IO.Jpeg.JpegDecoder Bad Quality

Tags: c#, silverlight, image-processing, jpeg

I'm using [ImageTools for Silverlight](http://imagetools.codeplex.com) to load a JPG image, but the decoded image quality is BAD (no anti-aliasing, see the second image in the red square).

Here is my code:

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    var stream = dlg.File.OpenRead();
    var newImg = new ExtendedImage(); // ExtendedImage is a ImageTools Api class
    var d= new ImageTools.IO.Jpeg.JpegDecoder();
    d.Decode(newImg, stream);
    image1.Source = newImg.ToBitmap(); //image1 is a System.Windows.Controls.Image
}
```

### Source image

[image: this is the source image]

### Bad result

[image: this is the bad result]

### Observations

**If I set `image1.source` directly to a URL from the original image, the image is rendered correctly!**

Is this a bug in the ImageTools API?

[The problem is posted on Codeplex](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/discussions/271019), but it doesn't have any answers.

If I rewrite my code, I get the same result.

#### XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="JPGDecoder.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Image Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,75,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Source="/JPGDecoder;component/Images/org.jpg" />
    <Image Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="212,75,0,0" Name="image2" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" />
    <Button Content="Decode JPG from File Stream" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,25,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

#### C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using ImageTools;

namespace JPGDecoder
{
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (dlg.ShowDialog()==true)
        {
            var stream = dlg.File.OpenRead();
            var newImg = new ExtendedImage();
            var d = new ImageTools.IO.Jpeg.JpegDecoder();
            d.Decode(newImg, stream);
            image2.Source = newImg.ToBitmap();
        }
    }
}
}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImageTools.IO.Jpeg.JpegDecoder Bad Quality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230834/imagetools-io-jpeg-jpegdecoder-bad-quality)

Comment: Please just adjust the content of your original question rather that asking the same one again.

Comment: i vote do delete first post,sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageTools does not support antialising, so I got [FJCore](http://fjcore.googlecode.com) from Subversion and ran the sample app.

1. First test same result, bad quality.
2. Looking at the source code, I found this code block:

   ```
   // Resize
   DecodedJpeg jpegOut = new DecodedJpeg(
       new ImageResizer(jpegIn.Image).Resize(320, ResamplingFilters.NearestNeighbor),
       jpegIn.MetaHeaders); // Retain EXIF details
   ```

   and changed it to this:

   ```
   //Resize
   DecodedJpeg jpegOut = new DecodedJpeg(
       new ImageResizer(jpegIn.Image).Resize(320, ResamplingFilters.LowpassAntiAlias),
       jpegIn.MetaHeaders); // Retain EXIF details
   ```

This is the solution: **ResamplingFilters.LowpassAntiAlias**

Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... I think it would be a good idea if you post a question to the [ImageTool codeplex forum](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/), this author used to answer quite fast.

Have you checked the samples from his site?

Usually I had no problems with this library.

Cheers
  Braulio

Comment: Covering the text "ImageTool codeplex forum" with a link to said forum would improve the quality of this answer.

Comment: i already post the problem on codeplex, http://imagetools.codeplex.com/discussions/271019, but no answers!!